# how can I create an RPM from a subdir?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a subdir my_sw that has an image of what I want to install:

```
my_sw/
  usr/
    bin/
       foo
    man/
       man1/
         foo.1
```

and so on.  I imagine there must be a simple way to create a spec file and use rpmbuild to package this up as an RPM so other users can install it.  I don't care about any of the fancy build stuff rpm can do, I just want it to install that dir tree.  (I suppose I'm misusing rpm a bit, but this way my users will have my files tracked in their rpm database, which they'd like.)

I've tried various things, but rpm wants to do way more than I want it to, and most projects want rpm to do lots more as well (pre-building, building, testing things, stripping, etc.)  Is there a howto somewhere showing how to just put together a trivial rpm that just installs files?

I'm doing this on CentOS 5 or 6 (or similar RedHat).

Comment: What rpm-based distribution and version are you targetting?

Comment: sorry, left that out. CentOS 5 and 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create RPMs from a filesystem image such as you describe.  It is one of the easier cases for RPM building, but you still have to use the tools.

The steps are roughly:

1) Create an RPM building environment, if you have not already done so.  At its barest, that would be a subdirectory tree under your home directory, like so:

```
rpm/
  BUILD/
  RPMS/
    x86_64/  (or whatever is the applicable arch)
  SOURCES/
  SPECS/
  SRPMS/
```

2) Create a tarball of the image, and drop it in the SOURCES/ directory.

3) Create a spec file in the SPEC/ subdirectory.  There are tools that can help you create a spec file skeleton.  For example, if the "rpmdevtools" package is available to you (which it is for CentOS 5 and 6) then you can use "rpmdev-newspec".  You will need to fill in some fields and provide some (minor, in your case) shell commands.  The result might be something like this:

```
Name:    my_sw
Summary: Cool software
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
Group:   Applications
License: <license>
Source0: my_sw.tar.gz

%description
my_sw does awesome things that you'll really like.  If you have any need for
awesomeness, this is for you!

%prep
# different from the default:
%setup -q -c -T

%build
# nothing to do

%install
# Start clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}

# Put the files in the correct location relative to %{buildroot}
ln -s %{buildroot} ./my_sw
tar xzf %{S:0}

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%{_bindir}/foo
%{_mandir}/man1/foo.1

%changelog
* Wed Aug 27 2014 Gary O <garyo@gmail.com> 1.0-1
- Initial spec
```

Some of that goes into the ultimate RPM; the rest tells rpmbuild details of what it needs to do.

4) Build it with rpmbuild:

```
rpmbuild -ba SPECS/my_sw.spec
```

5) The binary RPM will be in RPMS/.  The source RPM will be in SRPMS/.

One of the best RPM building references I have ever found is the Fedora Project's RPM guide: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/index.html.  See especially chapter 9.

Comment: For CentOS 5, you will need a BuildRoot field in the spec.  rpmdev-newspec will create a suitable one for you, if you use that to generate your initial skeleton.

Comment: For guidance on setting `BuildRoot` see: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingDrafts/SecureBuildRoot

Comment: I believe an rpm macro file to set `_topdir` will be necessary to use the home rpm build tree. Possibly also for CentOS 6 but I'm not sure. I believe that isn't necessary on CentOS 7 though.

Comment: Thanks!  Scripting this looks a little complicated, but should be doable.